# How to emit hair particles from other hairs

Tags: particles

I was trying to create moss (it's probably not moss, but still), and upon examining a patch of it from close, (IRL), I figured the easiest way to make it would be to have a particle systems that emits hairs, and them emit other hairs from each; however, I can't find a way to do this.

Is this possible (without the use of Particle Nodes, since the latest release was 2.62)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It *is* possible to do this non-destructively, but you must be using a mesh object for your first object.

1. Add a particle system your base object, then set the *Type* to *Object* and select your initial hair object:

   [image]
2. Add a hair particle system to the hair object:

   [image]

   The hair particles will also appear on each instance of the mesh object, but only in the render (this is probably a good thing :P).

Comment: Yeah... These were the approaches I was going to take; It's not ideal, but it works...

Comment: Also, don't you need the Particle Instance modifier?

Comment: @someonewithpc Nope, but that would probably work too.